# updating wordpress img urls

Tags: wordpress, url, image, src

Ive recently ported a wp site to a new host, i did this by exporting the db and then updating it to the new host, its all come across pretty easily but the main problem im having is the img src urls have added an extra `/` to them.

They should look like :

```
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/0007_cloud.png
```

but instead are like :

```
http://mydomain.com//wp-content/uploads/2012/04/0007_cloud.png
```

is there a way i can mass fix these broken urls ?

Comment: just also found the Velvet Blues Update URLs wordpress plugin which is useful for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use "[Search and replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)". It will safely replace all strings in database.